# LIBPATH option of referenced library project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a Static library project that depends on an external library. I've added the folder of the external library to the 'Additional Library Directories' setting of the Static library project. When I then create a project and add a reference to this Static library project it still fails to find the external lib file at link time. Only when I add the folder of the external lib to the 'Additional Library Directories' setting of the application project instead it finds the lib file.

Is there a way of adding something to /LIBPATH automatically so that each application project that references the Static library project automatically finds the external lib file? I don't really want to specify the folder in the general 'Library Directories' folder. I also can't use a '#pragma comment(linker, "/LIBPATH...")' instruction.